# Have 2 Different IActionResults, one with a parameter and one without a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to have to different IActionResults like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateTournament()
    {
        ViewData["Creator"] = "User";
        TournamentDTO tournamentDTO = new TournamentDTO()
        {
            OrganisationID = "null",
        };
        return View();
    }

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateTournament(string OrganisationID)
    {
        ViewData["Creator"] = "Org";
        TournamentDTO tournamentDTO = new TournamentDTO()
        {
            OrganisationID = OrganisationID,
        };
        return View();
    }
```

But when I try to navigate to this page it gives an error

> AbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
> F4DEDTournaments.Controllers.TournamentController.CreateTournament (F4DEDTournaments)
> F4DEDTournaments.Controllers.TournamentController.CreateTournament (F4DEDTournaments)

Is there a fix for this without putting both codeblocks in the same method like this?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateTournament(string OrganisationID)
    {
        if( OrganisationID == string.empty)}
        {
            ViewData["Creator"] = "User";
            TournamentDTO tournamentDTO = new TournamentDTO()
            {
                OrganisationID = "null",
            };
            return View();
        } else {
            ViewData["Creator"] = "Org";
            TournamentDTO tournamentDTO = new TournamentDTO()
            {
            OrganisationID = OrganisationID,
            };
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the URL for the second one look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action params are optional by default, so i would prefer one method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateTournament(string OrganisationID)
    {
        ViewData["Creator"] = OrganisationID == null? "Org" : "User";
        TournamentDTO tournamentDTO = new TournamentDTO()
        {
            OrganisationID = OrganisationID == null? "null" : OrganisationID
        };
        return View();
    }
```